# java spring mvc hello world type not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

This is my project:

**ProducerController .java:**

```
package mypackage.application;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/producer")
public class ProducerController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public String info() {
        return "hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/send", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public Email greeting() {
        return new Email("send@tome.com","hello");
    }
}
```

**Email.java**

```
public class Email {

    private String to;
    private String body;

    public Email(String to, String body) {
        this.to = to;
        this.body = body;
    }
    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }
    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }
    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }
    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

}
```

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses=ProducerController.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EbmApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I do the GET Request http://localhost:8080/producer/send or http://localhost:8080/producer/

I have returned this error message when the return is called:

**There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).**

What's wrong?
Thanks a lot

Comment: you tried with RestController  instead of @Controller ?

Comment: ok with @RestController works...why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **@RestController** instead of @Controller

```
 @RestController  
 @RequestMapping(value = "/producer")
    public class ProducerController {
    ....      
    }
```

The HTTP status code of 404 is precisely the appropriate
response status code when a resource isn’t found.
because now the controller is annotated
with @RestController, the objects returned from those methods will go through
message conversion to produce a resource representation for the client (browser).

Answer (score 2):

you are returning string "hello" from your method, which Spring thinks is a view name. I assume that in your case it is not, so try this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public String info() {
    return "hello";
}
```

so that "hello" would be the string returned from your method.

@RestController mentioned in the comment also works, it does the same thing - with that, returned strings are assumed to be content, not view names.